# Displaying a button link in “do not show images” mobile mode

Tags: html, button, mobile, hyperlink, imageview

I have a page on a third-party site. On the page a have a linked button and it works perfectly on PC, but while I am browsing my page on my Iphone I got a mobile version of the third-party site for my page. In this version all images are removed. I need to save the button hyperlink as a linked text somehow. Could someone help with it? Thanks.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Yes, please.    `<a title="Регистрация" href="http://naraione.ecommtools.com/buy/2" target="_blank"><img title="Регистрация" src="https://evbdn.eventbrite.com/s3-s3/eventlogos/70887017/d180d0b5d0b3d0b8d181d182d180d0b0d186d0b8d18fd0bad0bdd0bed0bfd0bad0b004.jpg" alt="" width="148" height="34" />`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `alt=""` to `alt="some text here"` inside the `<img>` tag.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried it already - it does not work out - alt-text does not show up on a mobile version of the third-party site.